# PyUsb: "insufficient permissions". macOS Big Sur

Tags: python, macos, usb, macos-big-sur, pyusb

I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xfhzbw93rzw) tutorial for pyusb but when I get this far into the code, I get the error: `raise USBError(_strerror(ret), ret, _libusb_errno[ret]) usb.core.USBError: [Errno 13] Access denied (insufficient permissions)`. Here is the code I wrote:

```
import usb.core
import usb.util

VID = 0x046d
PID = 0xc07e
dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=VID, idProduct=PID)
ep = dev[0].interfaces()[0].endpoints()[0]
i = dev[0].interfaces()[0].bInterfaceNumber
dev.reset()
if dev.is_kernel_driver_active(i):
    dev.detach_kernel_driver(i)

r = dev.read(eaddr, 1024)
print(len(r))
```

As I said in the title, I'm on macOS Big Sur Version 11.4 and I'm trying to read from `Bus 020 Device 029: ID 046d:c07e Logitech Inc. Gaming Mouse G402`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error says "Access denied (insufficient permissions)". You have to run your code with sudo. Like: "sudo python3 <yourscript.py>".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).